# Особенности дебага в Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, отладка

Происходит отладка Android приложения в IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2.

Движемся строка за строкой. Допустим, требуется войти в какую-либо функцию (F7). Видимо при этом что-то происходит не так, потому как в этот момент происходит выброс куда-то в "родной" класс, который к тому же весь покрыт красным. Не привык к этому, так как ранее не занимался Android приложениями, а просто писал на Java. Что это за явление и как это можно убрать? Ибо отладка на этом, собственно и стопорится.

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Что за функция?

Comment: @Alex78191 Да в принципе ничего особенного - она считает индекс совпадения (Фридмана) для русского текста. По сути дела, просто математические вычисления. Параметром передаётся текст с EditText поля в виде editable.toString().

Просто я такое уже не в первый раз вижу при отладке. Это дело не в функции.

Comment: Shift+F8 выйти из функции (step out), рано или поздно вернетесь себе в код. У вас просто подключены исходники, в которые вы проваливаетесь, естественно исходники и бинарники по номерам строк не совпадают, ничего особенного и страшного в этом нет.

Comment: @YuraIvanov  Угу. Ну ладно, спасибо тогда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, как оказалось с этим действительно ничего не поделать и можно просто нажимать Shift+F8 до возвращения к исходному коду. Избежать этого что-то настраивая изначально нельзя.